# Android: Change fragment on touch/swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Is it possible to achieve interaction between fragments described in this image:

[image]

So, if one touches (or preferably swipes vertically) on fragment B, it shows (or is replaced by) fragment C and changes size to accommodate the larger fragment. Fragment C will contain a viewPager with additional fragments that are revealed on horizontal swipe (this part is done).

Fragment B will display the crucial contents of fragment C, which is why I want a separate fragment to do this. Fragment A takes user input and should always be interact-able.

I need help wrapping my head around how this should be implemented.